# Extracting data values from a table with BeautifulSoup not working for me

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, jupyter

For some data analysis I need to extract a list of the class "timeUsage" (move times for professional chess players making their moves) of this webpage https://chess24.com/en/watch/live-tournaments/11th-batavia-chess-tournament-2019/4/1/1. The class is visible when inspecting the source of the table to the right of the chess problem. I have tried using BeautifulSoup but it is not working for me and I hope someone wants to take a look for me :)

I have requested the webpage in Jupyter Notebook and installed the BeautifulSoup library. I will show below what I have tried.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://chess24.com/en/watch/live-tournaments/11th-batavia-chess-tournament-2019/4/1/1')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

timeUsages = soup.find_all("span", attrs={"class": "timeUsage"})
```

Now I would like the list of the timeUsage values, which I need but I get nothing. If anyone with experience with this library would like to help me, thank you very much!

Comment: this page uses JavaScript to add content but BS doesn't run JavaScript. Try `Selenium` to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: I will give that a try thanks, I don't understand how JavaScript makes that he could not find the values in the HTML since the class is in the source in the same way that I saw in tutorials, but I am not theoretically deep into programming languages so hopefully Selenium can help me.

Comment: these elements don't exists in HTML but they can be added by JavaScript. You should `print(r.text)` to see what you get. You can even check `print("timeUsage" in r.text)` and you should get `False`. The same `print(r.text.find("timeUsage"))` should give `-1` which means it couldn't find `"timeUsage"` in string `r.text`

Comment: [Selenium-Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: Okay thank you very much, I see what you mean now. However one thing is going wrong, I installed Selenium and ran:

Comment: browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://chess24.com/en/watch/live-tournaments/11th-batavia-chess-tournament-2019/4/1/1'), However now I get FileNotFound errors and the message that geckodriver needs to be in PATH. Is there any way for me to show a picture here?

Comment: it may need [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.25.0) to control Firefox browser, or [chromdriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/) to control Chromium browser.

Comment: Thanks so much furas, it finally worked now with chromedriver!